# Function doesn't return value

Tags: php, function

For some reason this function won't return the value `ciao`:

```
$a = "ciao";

function a() {
    return $a;
}
```

I have no idea why.

Comment: Read http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php. It is explained right at the top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Functions can only return variables they have in their local space, called scope:

```
$a = "ciao";

function a() {
    $a = 'hello`;
    return $a;
}
```

Will return `hello`, because within `a()`, `$a` is a variable of it's own. If you need a variable within the function, pass it as parameter:

```
$a = "ciao";

function a($a) {
    return $a;
}
echo a($a); # "ciao"
```

BTW, if you enable [NOTICES to be reported](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) (`error_reporting(-1);`), PHP would have given you notice that `return $a` in your original code was using a undefined variable.

Answer (score 3):

In PHP, functions don't have access to global variables. Use `global $a` in body of the function or pass the value of $a as parameter.

Comment: Don't suggest using `global`, suggest using a function parameter instead.

Answer (score 2):

`$a` is not in scope within the function.

PHP does not work with a closure like block scope that JS works with for instance, if you wish to access an external variable in a function, you must pass it in which is sensible, or use `global` to make it available, which is frowned on.

```
$a = "ciao";

function a() {
    global $a;
    return $a;
}
```

or with a closure style in PHP5.3+

```
function a() use ($a) {
    return $a;
}
```